# Design pattern to support additional vendor in existing application

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We have a application built using C# used for sending notification. For sending notification we are use third party SOAP service. Now we have to add support for new third part api which provides same functionality of sending notification.

The existing C# application uses plain OOP concept. Since now we have to modify application to support a new vendor I am thinking on using/applying some design pattern if available so that we can support additional vendors easily in future.

Has anyone faced this issue or aware which design pattern would solve the problem.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: BTW, since you are asking for a Design Pattern, the question isn't really C# specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a Facade that provides the required functionality for sending messages. Your application only works with the Facade, not directly with the vendors SOAP service.

For each vendor you create an implementation of the Facade that uses this vendor's SOAP service. This implementation can live in a new assembly, completely decoupling your application from the vendor's SOAP services. You could now even support other mechanism that are not SOAP based.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the adapter pattern.

The adapter pattern is when you setup a layer between your internal system and the place you're getting data from.  All that this layer does is transform the data from their format into yours.

This means that if you have multiple sources of data you can transform them all into one accepted format and pass them into your system, and if the data format at their end changes you only need to update your adapter, rather than lower level code.

edit: Daniel is right, a Facade is more appropriate.  Adapters like I've described are more about sending data between sources.A facade sits between sources in a similar way and transforms methods, rather than in my solution which transforms data.